# Updating multiple radiobuttons in one observer only works on the first radiobutton

Tags: r, shiny, radio-button, shinyjs

I'm completely puzzled why two working lines of code (individually), which `reset` a respective `radiobutton` to empty (`selected = character(0)`) only `reset` the first line when put together inside 1 'observer'

this is the minimal example:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  tags$script("
    Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('resetValue', function(variableName) {
                  Shiny.onInputChange(variableName, null);
                  });
                  "),
  radioButtons("radio","Click Me",choices  = c("Choice 1","Choice s"),selected = character(0)),
  radioButtons("radio2","Click Me",choices  = c("Choice 1","Choice s"),selected = character(0)),
  actionButton("clickMe","Click Me to Reset"),
  actionButton("showValue", "Show value")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$clickMe,{
    session$sendCustomMessage(type = "resetValue", message ='radio')
    updateRadioButtons(session,"radio",choices  = c("Choice 1","Choice s"),selected = character(0))
    session$sendCustomMessage(type = "resetValue", message ='radio2')

    updateRadioButtons(session,"radio2",choices  = c("Choice 1","Choice s"),selected = character(0))

  })

  observeEvent(input$showValue, {
    print(input$radio)
    print(input$radio2)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

where the `sendcustomMessages` are used to `reset` the `values`, which is not achieved by selecting `character(0)`, which comes from i.e. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45315106/shiny-how-to-send-updated-data-with-renderui-and-eventreactive)

Comment: apparently there have been some issues before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54772944/reset-radiobuttons-in-shiny-to-empty-value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Update

I am not able to figure out why it is not possible to update two radioButtons in one reactiveEvent, but the error seems to stem from setting the `selected =` argument to `character(0)`. And while the first `updateRadioButtons` works with `character(0)` the second doesn't.

Changing `character(0)`to `0` in the `selected =` argument of the `updateRadioButtons` produces the desired result and somehow does not cause said problem/bug. Comparing the buttons values, there seems to be no difference between setting the buttons initially to `character(0)` or `0`. Both ways the button values are `NULL`. After reseting the values with the custom JavaScript function the value is updated in JS to `null`.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  tags$script("
              Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('resetValue', function(variableName) {
              Shiny.onInputChange(variableName, null);
              });
              "),
  radioButtons("radio","Click Me",choices  = c("Choice 1","Choice s"),selected = character(0)),
  radioButtons("radio2","Click Me",choices  = c("Choice 1","Choice s"),selected = character(0)),
  actionButton("clickMe","Click Me to Reset"),
  actionButton("showValue", "Show value")
  )

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$clickMe,{
    session$sendCustomMessage(type = "resetValue", message ='radio')
    updateRadioButtons(session,"radio",choices  = c("Choice 1","Choice s"),selected = 0)
    session$sendCustomMessage(type = "resetValue", message ='radio2')

    updateRadioButtons(session,"radio2",choices  = c("Choice 1","Choice s"),selected = 0)

  })

  observeEvent(input$showValue, {
    print(input$radio)
    print(input$radio2)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```